# Sending a link in email to member with no login required when returning to site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm sending members of my site emails after an event so they can rate and tip their teachers. Is there a way to create some unique key and include this in the email link back to my site so they can rate and tip without having to login back in? If so what's the best way to do this? Is there something in Asp.Net identity?

It looks like Uber might be doing this with their tip link below but I'm not sure.

> https://gratitude.uber.com/tips/trip/33879346-bba8-406a-82a8-2afcda9aa3e7

Answer (score 0):

Add the users to a database and then send the link with their UserId as a query string:

```
www.mysite.co.uk/survey?id=4546
```

Create a controller called surveycontroller with a parameter to capture the id and direct to the survey html page.

Comment: I think I'm looking for something a little more secure! Using this approach anyone could get to this page if they knew another's id right? Isn't there a better way with some type of encrypted token or something?

Comment: You could generate a guid and store that in the database and put that in the query string, it would then be harder to copy another users string.

Comment: I'm thinking more about it now and wondering if it's really needed? Is a user id in the url secure enough? I'm just a little hesitant because they can tip from this page using a previously stored credit card.They won't be re entering in the number, but there is still a transaction occurring

Comment: If the most they can do is answer some questions and they aren't given any information about the person with id=4546, then this should be secure enough.

Comment: they will be able to rate, provide a comment for the reviews section and then if they have a credit card on file they will have the option to tip (this will be in a drop box. ex $1.00, $2.00, $3.00, etc). Then they submit!

Comment: Then you need to get them to login to the site, otherwise they can spend someone else's money!

Comment: I think your right, but that's why I was wondering about some unique token or key I could generate to include in the url. I didn't know if there was a secure way to have the member get to my site using this unique key? Then I could somehow check the key against some stored key or something? Kinda like the post above by lvl4fi4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156383/discussion-between-rob-anthony-and-user1186050).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14403/Generating-Unique-Keys-in-Net)

> The .net Framwork provides RNGCryptoServiceProvider class which
>   Implements a cryptographic Random Number Generator (RNG) using the
>   implementation provided by the cryptographic service provider (CSP).
>   This class is usually used to generate random numbers. Although I can
>   use this class to generate unique number in some sense but it is also
>   not collision less. Moreover while generating key we can make key more
>   complicated by making it as alpha numeric rather than numeric only.
>   So, I used this class along with some character masking to generate
>   unique key of fixed length. Below is code sample:

```
private string GetUniqueKey() { int maxSize = 8 ; int minSize = 5 ; char[] chars = new char[62]; string a; a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"; chars = a.ToCharArray(); int size = maxSize ; byte[] data = new byte[1]; RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider(); crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data) ; size = maxSize ; data = new byte[size]; crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data); StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(size) ; foreach(byte b in data ) { result.Append(chars[__b % (chars.Length - )>); } <span class="code-keyword">return result.ToString(); }
```

As you mentioned in comments there might be security issues,  you can use blow method to avoid them:

- check for user last ip address loged in with to know this is actually the user opening the link
- check for user cookies
- create block list for subspecies bruteForce attack
- make the generated key disabled and enable it after all above security passed
- use captcha verification to avoid BruteForce or non human access your page

Comment: so if I used a unique key, would I then associate this key with a user for a specific event, then when the user hits the controller's action I would then check to see who the user is based on the key?

Comment: @user1186050 yes, for more security you may want to invalidate the key after he/she used the key to submit data and generate new one for new event.

Comment: would you recommend this as a secure way to get a member to a page where they will submit a tip? ex. drop down box with values like $1.00, $2.00, $3.00. I'm looking at Uber's tip page for examples. Because I don't think I need to be logged in to tip, or it doesn't seem like it. I could be wrong!

Comment: @user1186050 yes I've seen alot example of this way in many applications,  as long as you protect the key there is no security issues

Comment: what do you mean by protect the key?

Comment: @user1186050 make it unpredictable and one-time use. So the attacker can't generate one or attack with bruteForce

Comment: yes it will def be a one time use key, but what do you mean unpredictable? Isn't the algorithm generating the key value?

Comment: @user1186050 yes,  so don't worry about that

Comment: @user1186050 if you want make it more secure,  after generating the key you can make it disable against brutForce and check for last ip address of user, if user changed his ip adress then ask for login that updates the user ip address then he/she can get to enable the generated key and submit the data and key will invalidate

Comment: @user1186050 and also if you use cookies,  you can combine checking cookies with your algorithm and make it more secure